# findOneAndUpdate promise always resolving. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise, findoneandupdate

I made email verification function and problem is that findOneAndUpdate function always resolve no matter what.

I have **empty database**, so I guess findOneAndUpdate function **should fail**, but it succeeds.

I guess my mistake is somewhere in this function

```
User.activate = function(activationLink) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        usersCollection.findOneAndUpdate({"activationLink": activationLink}, {"$set": {"isActivated": true}}).then(function(userDoc) {
            if (userDoc) {
                resolve('Your account has been activated!')
            } else {
                reject('This account does not exist!')
            }
        }).catch((e) => {
            reject(e)
        })
    })
}
```

I'll add this just in case.
userController.js:

```
exports.activate = function(req, res){
    User.activate(req.params.activationLink).then((result) => {
        res.send(result)
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.send(e)
    })
}
```

router.js:

```
router.get('/activate/:activationLink', userController.activate)
```

Comment: What is the value of `userDoc`? Sidenote: `usersCollection.findOneAndUpdate` already returns a `Promise`. That means you can return the promise from that function. This is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Is there any good reason why you promisfy an promise?

Comment: `findOneAndUpdate` updates a document in case there is a match in the query filter. Otherwise the update fails and its not an error.